# How do i replace 'view Ember.TextField' with 'input' in an emblem template?

Tags: emblem.js

I recently updated to Ember 1.8.0 and using `view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"` throws a deprecation error.  Per the [deprecation guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views-since-1-8) it should be replaced with the `input` helper, but the following doesn't work

```
input valueBinding="name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `=` to the line so that emblem treats it as a helper invocation

```
= input valueBinding="name"
```

The same is true for updating `view Ember.Select`.  See the discussion [here](https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/issues/178).

```
= view 'select'
```